# Using Stream Cipher as CSPRNG

Tags: stream-cipher, random-number-generator

Are there any guidelines or justification for converting a stream cipher algorithm for use as a CSPRNG?

For instance, lets say I wanted to convert one of the eStream portfolio Profile 1 (software) selections for use as a CSPRNG. What I could do is generate a really unique hash from some other algorithm and use it as the key. Then I could generate another really unique, lets say 64-bits, and use it as the initialization variable. Now, what are my options? I could continue regenerating output blocks based on the cipher's internal variables. I could try to encode an incrementing counter into the block stream and then get the output. I could regenerate a key and (iv) and get the output again (seems costly).

I read that it's generally not smart to re-use the key on multiple encodings, so that makes me think I should just keep regenerating the first output block. Is the original output block by definition an unending random stream?

Comment: Why is it not sufficient to use the CSPRNG built into your operating system? `/dev/urandom` on any *nix, `CryptGenRandom` on Windows.

Comment: Great question. That binds portability of the application to a specific version of an OS or runtime environment. This is for an app that requires a high degree of regulatory scrutiny. They also, apparently, do not like exposed public APIs. These are just the parameters I'm given for the problem.

Comment: I don't understand how "they... do not like exposed public APIs". Unless you're building a language and runtime environment from scratch, you're using public APIs. If you include any of the eStream portfolio, you're using public APIs.

Comment: Let's just say they have a philosophy where it comes to using publicly posted code for things that tangibly impact the flow of money, like RNGs and ciphers. We fly our own code from algorithms in reference texts.

Comment: Where is the seed for your CSPRNG supposed to come from?

Comment: The seed comes from /dev/random -> SHA hashing -> Exposed language RNG. Then it's transformed by cutting up bits and reassembling using an algorithm for unique IDs described in a well-known RFC. Random portions of the stream are encrypted (different algorithm) and reassembled in place. This may seem like overkill until one considers the exposed RNG contract as its own entity. This is an attempt to remove trace patterns, torn on whether it's overkill.

Comment: The app is BTW portable and using /dev/random wouldn't be useful anyway for a performant application since there would be slices of unexpected wait for entropy to rebuild itself in the core. Fortuna (mentioned here) tries to work around that by having multiple entropy pools. Writing a multi-threaded, safe, performant and truly entropic Fortuna is akin to sleeping on a bed of nails. (Can be done but maybe not pleasant.)

Comment: As to the comments above that are akin to saying, "Gee, why not just use code on the Internet?" Generally, reference code and academic papers are good library material, but very bad production code. The key phrase here is "requires a high degree of regulatory scrutiny" which itself can be decrypted to mean the stuff is certified. Kerckhoff's Principle does not decry SBO, it just says make your tool good enough so that it's secure when the nemesis has a copy (not the key).

Answer (score 4):

Using a stream cipher for mass generation of "random" bytes is a fairly good solution, however the risk is loosing [Forward Secrecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) at some point. The trick then is re-keying the cipher often enough, and having a good source of random data with which to rekey your cipher.

See [Fortuna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_%28PRNG%29).

Comment: Okay, but for 64- or 32-bit primitives that generally should not apply, right? Unless, I am using a really bad cipher with a very small (< 32-bit) internal state, which I am not planning. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your threat model before folks can give more concrete advice. There is a big difference in just needing a few thousand pseudo-random values and needing cryptographically secure values.

Comment: Thanks. The threat model is an online, publicly exposed application processing large sums of money that will be subject to frequent attempts to reverse engineer the number stream. It needs to be close to a TRBG/TRNG. HW RNG is not available.

Comment: Then you must use a real CSPRNG which is continuously reseeded like Fortuna. A stream cipher alone is not good enough, as it has a trivial distinguisher from a purely random stream: outputs won't repeat until the counter overflows. If you're running this on any *nix, use `/dev/urandom`. If on Windows, use `CryptGenRandom`. If on both platforms, use an `if` statement and pick whichever one is available. Your scenario is precisely the type where a poor technical decision like writing your own RNG can result in catastrophic financial consequences.

Comment: There's no reason why an API or other library is better coded than something written privately by a single good developer. OpenSSL is a great case-study in this point. And, so is Dual_EC_DRBG.

Comment: Yes, there *absolutely* is. Cryptography is hard, and if you believe it's a simple exercise to write secure code to a public spec, you're in for a bad time. Established companies with huge security teams like [Amazon](http://rdist.root.org/2009/05/20/amazon-web-services-signature-vulnerability/), [Google](http://rdist.root.org/2009/05/28/timing-attack-in-google-keyczar-library/), and [Facebook](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/01/24/facebook_bug_bounty_payout/) can get details wrong. The notion that a developer with no cryptographic background working solo will do a better job is laughable.

Comment: @StephenTouset The "outputs won't repeat" distinguisher is not universal for stream ciphers, I think, just for counter mode block ciphers or similar stuff. E.g. if you use a stream cipher build from a PRF in CTR mode, it will repeat just as often as expected for a true random stream.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann You'd need a pretty large amount of data to prove that it will not repeat anyway, even for a block cipher in CTR mode (at least, I assume we are talking about repetition of aligned blocks here, repetition of smaller amounts is completely possible in any sense).